# IntelliJ 2023.1 highlights that Kotlin functions cannot be found

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, intellij-plugin

If I open a Spring project, IntelliJ, with version 2023.1, shows the following errors:
[image]

When you hover over the highlights, it says: "Unresolved Reference: x"
Although these "errors" appear, I can build and run the project perfectly.

When I open the same project with the previous IntelliJ version, everything is works perfectly.

This problem appeared out of nowhere a few weeks ago. Before that, everything worked fine with version 2023.1. I cannot explain why this suddenly happened.

I would be happy about any advice :)

Comment: Have you tried "File" -> "Invalidate caches" and "Invalidate and Restart"?